# Performing named-entity recognition on sentences that are poorly cased to extract company names

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a database of sentences from which I am trying to extract any and all **company names**. As of now, I am using spaCy's Named Entity Recognition and achieve good results for the sentences that have standard capitalization.
The problem arises when I try to do the same thing for sentences that do NOT have standard capitalization. In particular, I get poor performance for the subset of the database that use "title casing" (i.e. all words apart from prepositions/articles/etc. are capitalized).

Here are some examples of these kind of sentences along with the current result I get with spaCy, and the result that I want:

| Sentence | Current Extraction | Desired Extraction(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Caribbean Airlines Transforms its Revenue Accounting Process | Caribbean Airlines Transforms its Revenue Accounting | Caribbean Airlines |
| Scoular Drives Employee Development With Absorb LMS | Scoular Drives Employee Development With Absorb | (Scoular, Absorb LMS) |
| Oracle Solution Reduces Operating Costs by 25 Percent | Oracle Solution Reduces Operating Costs | Oracle |
| Pandora CFO Cuts Procurement Time with Coupa | Pandora CFO Cuts Procurement Time | (Pandora, Coupa) |

As you can see the excess of capitalization makes spaCy believe that a lot more words are part of the entity name than is actually the case.
So my question is how can I mitigate this issue? Are there other libraries that are maybe not so sensitive to such capitalization or maybe I can preprocess the sentences by "truecasing" them. What are the standard procedures?

Just for completeness sake, here is how I use the spaCy library

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
for sentence in sentences:
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        ... store in database (ORG) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have an idea of possible solutions...

I'd advice:

- Preprocess and truecase sentences (quite complex / hard)
- Use other frameworks (e.g. BERT) which have uncased models
- Re-train Spacy's model with adequate data (which have to be annnotated)